# Vuetify - align centers of div, line and button

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I need to align the centers of these 4 Vuetify divs at the bottom.

And just to be absolutely clear, here is a screen shot with a red line that I'd like to align everything too. [Screen shot with red line](http://nimb.ws/dxpkH6)

```
  <v-container grid-list-lg>
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex mb-5>
      <!--<v-flex xs12 text-xs-center mb-5 v-if="selected_marketplaces != ''">-->
        <div xs2 pt-3 px-5 class="complete_progress_dots"></div>
        <div xs2 class="horizontal_dotted_line"></div>
        <div xs2 pt-3 px-5 class="not_complete_progress_dots"></div>
        <v-btn offset-xs2 outline large fab class="dark_green_icon" >
          <v-icon size="60px">chevron_right</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-flex>            
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
```

Here is the css for those:

```
.horizontal_dotted_line {
  border:none;
  border-top: 1px dotted #3b9542;
  color:#fff;
  background-color: #3b9542;
  height:1px;
  width:150px;
  display: inline-block;
}


.not_complete_progress_dots {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #3b9542;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px !important;
  margin-left: 50px !important;

}

.complete_progress_dots {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #3b9542;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-right: 50px !important;
  margin-left: 50px !important;
}

.dark_green_icon {
  color: #3b9542 !important;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle`?

Comment: That did it.. geez, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;`. It works.

Comment: ofcourse, but no helpers exist or what? Havent found one